# Can someone tell me how to get a variable with a certain length of characters?

Tags: php, regex

I have multiple vars:

```
$var1 = type_1_12345_123;
$var2= type_1_12345_343143;
$var3 = type_2_43123_123;
```

I want to select all variable which start with the format of 'type_1_12345'.

How can i do that? thank you.

Comment: what do you mean? names of variables? you can't write "var 1 = ..."

Comment: What does that mean exactly? You're wildly searching for variables in your current scope? Like `$type_1_12345 = 'foo'; $name = ??`? Then you're doing it wrong and need to use an array instead.

Comment: All variables from where? Scope? File? All files? The server? Defined variables? The request? External server? The moon?

Comment: Do you have *constants* defined by the name of `type_1_12345_123`, or why are you insisting on it *without quotes*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`preg_grep`**](https://www.php.net/preg_grep)

- Put all the strings into an array
- Perform a regular expression with `preg_grep()`

```
<?php

$a = array();
$a[] = "type_1_12345_53213";
$a[] = "type_1_12345_required";
$a[] = "type_3_43213_34523";

$matches = preg_grep("/^type_1_12345/", $a);

echo print_r($matches, true);
```

https://eval.in/198817

Answer (score -1):

Go through the vars and check the string to start with `type_1_12345` using substring.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
  if (substr(${'var'.$i},0,12) == 'type_1_12345') { 
    echo "var$i starts with 'type_1_12345'."; 
  }
}
```